# Errors upon searching in Elasticsearch using PHP

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am trying to search through my index using PHP. I have downloaded the vendor files and I have built the connection successfully. However, I am receiving some errors. These errors don't always occur though. If I refresh the browser a couple of times, I will get the correct output. Here's my code:

```
require_once 'init.php';

$json = '{"aggs": { "group_by_date": { "terms": { "field": "arrivalDate" } } } }';

    $params = [
        'index' => 'pickups',
        'type' => 'external',
        'body' => $json 
        ];
    
$results = $es->search($params);

echo $results['hits']['total'];
```

The init.php is the connection file to Elasticsearch. There are 2 different outputs that may occur upon refreshing the screen. The first output is the correct output. The other is just errors. Here are the errors:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\Missing404Exception: {"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found"} in C:\wamp64\www\DataAggregation\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection.php on line 602
>
> Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\Missing404Exception: {"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found"} in C:\wamp64\www\DataAggregation\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection.php on line 602
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception:   in C:\wamp64\www\DataAggregation\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection.php on line 610

What are the cause of these errors and how can I fix them?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not started web server, start ES web server to connect with php.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, when you say run the ES web server do you mean running elasticsearch.bat in the command line?

Comment: I am running elasticsearch, however, it's still displaying the same errors. I am running this using WAMP server in localhost:81

Comment: run elasticsearch.bat. it will show you port number on wich es service is running. open localhost with ES port in browser it will show you ES home page.

Comment: The Elasticsearch localhost port number is 9200, should I make port 9200 the port for WAMP server for PHP?

Comment: no you should not change port of WAMP server. Is localhost:9200 working? 9200 is default port of ES. if you can see ES home page then ES is working fine and you should check connection setting to connect with PHP

Comment: Yes, the connection to ES is working fine. If I create a normal web page in PHP with no ES, it works fine. When I add this line to execute the query: `$results = $es->search($params);` it gives me errors.

Comment: try $params = [
        '_index' => 'pickups',
        '_type' => 'external',
        'body' => $json 
        ];

Comment: It's now saying that _index and _type are not fail parameters

Comment: If I refresh the browser multiple times with my original code, it sometimes gives me the correct output with no errors

Comment: as per doc  https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php#search-for-a-document       require_once 'init.php';

$json = [query => [match => ["aggs" => [ "group_by_date" => [ "terms"=> [ "field" =>  "arrivalDate" ]]]]]];

    $params = [
        'index' => 'pickups',
        'type' => 'external',
        'body' => $json 
        ];

$results = $es->search($params);

echo $results['hits']['total'];